# EasyAdmin 3: limit data to the logged-in user still shows other data in form dropdowns

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I'm using Symfony 5.

I want every logged in user to have it's own space in EasyAdmin 3, so no user will see records of other users. I store the user with every table in the database.

For simple list views, I managed to get this to work using a extension of the `AbstractCrudController`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FieldCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FilterCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\SearchDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Orm\EntityRepository;

abstract class CustomCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        $qb = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
        $qb->andWhere('entity.user = :user');
        $qb->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());
        return $qb;
    }
}
```

I also store/check the user through a `EventSubscriber`.

Problem is, some forms have a relation to another Entity(like `AssociationField::new('food')`) and when filling the dropdowns it ignores my new function. So you will see records belonging to another user.

How do I override these dropdowns to also only show data belonging to the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: pass a custom query to the underlying `EntityType` field of Symfony.

```
AssociationField::new('food')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->setFormTypeOptions(['query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $em) {
    return $em->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->where('f.user = :user')
        ->orderBy('f.title', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('user', $this->getUser())
        ;
}]),
```